# How to access information from callback

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I just want to know how to get data from within the callback.

```py
import pika


def callback(channel, method, properties, body):
    print(method.get_body())
    print(method.get_properties())
    channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

def on_open(connection):
    connection.channel(on_open_callback=on_channel_open)


def on_channel_open(channel):
    channel.basic_consume(on_message_callback = callback, queue='q1')
    channel.basic_consume(on_message_callback = callback, queue='q2')


credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('user', 'password', erase_on_connect=False)
params = pika.ConnectionParameters("localhost", 5672, '/', credentials)

connection = pika.SelectConnection(parameters=params,
                                   on_open_callback=on_open)

try:
    connection.ioloop.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    connection.close()

    connection.ioloop.start()
```

The output to the two print lines in callback are:

```
<class 'pika.spec.Basic.Deliver'>
<Basic.Deliver(['consumer_tag=ctag1.2607da3f5f9f4e5592991a16cc0aca6e', 'delivery_tag=1', 'exchange=gatekeeper', 'redelivered=True', 'routing_key=laa'])>
```

How can I extract the 'routing_key'? Having a look at the source code it led me to believe `method.get_properties()` would work, but it did not.

Comment: `method.routing_key` should be how you get the routing key.

Comment: reply as an answer so I can accept this, legendary stuff bro. (Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although poorly documented, the `callback` function will be called with 4 arguments:

- The channel you consumed with
- A `Method` instance (in this case a [`Deliver`](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/spec.html#pika.spec.Basic.Deliver) instance)
- A [`BasicProperties`](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/spec.html#pika.spec.BasicProperties) instance
- A body (`bytes`)

The `Deliver` instance will have an attribute called `routing_key`. So your function could look like this:

```
def callback(channel, method, properties, body):
    print(method.get_body())
    print(method.get_properties())
    print(method.routing_key)
    channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
```

PS. The arguments the callback will be called with are the same as described in [here](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/adapters/blocking.html#pika.adapters.blocking_connection.BlockingChannel.basic_consume), where they *are* actually documented.

Comment: "Although poorly documented..." If [this documentation](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/master/pika/channel.py#L282-L288) is insufficient I would be thrilled to get a pull request to improve it, thanks. https://github.com/pika/pika

Comment: My apologies. I seem to have missed that bit. Where was I looking at then? I will still fidget about a little bit... maybe I'll figure out how to format it nicely in the html (eg not on a single line [like it is now](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/channel.html#pika.channel.Channel.basic_consume))